# How to level an area that was once a vegetable garden?

Tags: lawn, raised-beds

I have a leveled yard, all except for one area of the yard which was a vegetable garden many years ago.

The area is built up with cinder blocks and filled with dirt.

How do I remove both to level the area like the rest of the yard?

Comment: Please post a photograph or two of the area; it may help us give you specific advice for your requirements. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Are the blocks laid dry?

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of a fun project.  Go to a rental equipment place and get a little bobcat.  They deliver and pick up as well! They teach you how to use it (very simple) and takes just a few minutes to master.  Using the bucket you pick up physically and place the cinder blocks in the bucket to move somewhere else (do you need a garden wall somewhere? don't trash them for sure if at all possible).  If not using a bobcat you can do by using a tarp and dragging to where you want.  Then rake smooth and compact with a water drum roller that you can also rent.  Then reseed for lawn.  If plant beds don't do the compaction part. They also have 'dingos' that work just as well!  Think about drainage...having some slope away and not allowing puddles.

Answer (score 3):

Buy a slab of beer, some steak and sausages and invite your mates around :-) You'll be surprised what 6 blokes with shovels will get done in a few hours.

That said per stormy's answer it is probably a good excuse for hiring a machine. For this a mini-loader will probably do but I've found mini-excavators more useful generally. They are a little more complex to learn and a bit more expensive to hire but they are worth it. Many mini-excavators will have a dozer blade on the front for the final levelling out.

Answer (score 3):

How you do this will depend on size of job to be done, mini digger for largish area by yourself, and beer and mates for small areas both excellent ideas and workable solutions.  What size is the job you need to do?

There is always the option to have a split level garden if your circumstances dictate.